# Background-image for TD tag with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, background-image

I have this code -

```
<td id="td_h1" runat="server" style="background-image:url(images/img_new.jpg);vertical-align:top">
<div id="title_1" runat="server" class="caption" >This is New</div>
</td>
```

Here's the problem -
this is the code from the .master.aspx page. Some file accesses this master page from different folders, and some files from root. And the img_new is visible only from root files or files in folder. How do I make that image visible from everywhere?

Comment: You need to learn to ask better questions. For instance, is this problem specific to "td" tags?

Comment: thanks. yes this problem is specific to <td> tags and backround-image to be visible from everywhere

Comment: So, if you used `<div style="background-image:url(...)"/>` then it works? But it doesn't work with `td`?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

1. You can use an absolute path, like this: `url(/BaseDir/images/img_new.jpg)`
2. You can call [`ResolveClientUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl.aspx), which will return the correct path, like this:

   url(<%=ResolveClientUrl("images/img_new.jpg")%>)

**EDIT**: `ResolveClientUrl` takes a relative URL, so it should not start with `~/`.  Try again without `~/`.

Comment: i tried this -
<td id="td_h1" runat="server" style="background-image:url(<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/images/img_new.jpg")%>)">

Nothing happened

Comment: What HTML did it produce? Is your `images` folder directly in the application root?